# Old Style Tabs In Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse

any way I can bring back the tab style of indigo? I don't like the new white and block tabs!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Windows -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Theme. Select "Classic".

Afterwards restart once, as some changes cannot be applied immediately.

Answer (score 1):

For those who wish to move to using the Eclipse Indigo looks, a version prior, simply, rename the folder,

plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0.v201206081400\css

to something like,

plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0.v201206081400\css.old

And you are done! Launch your eclipse and enjoy the old theme.

**Note**:

Make sure Eclipse is not-running when making this change.

In Eclipse juno SR1 the folder is **org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800**