# Change the appearance of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse and I don't like the appearance of the user interface, it's to much white color in the background. I have used Eclipse earlier, and then it was better with not all that white area! I have been looking in the preference, but have not found any places to change the user interface. Is there a theme that could be changed !?

Comment: Potential duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120621/dark-color-scheme-for-eclipse

Answer (score 9):

Open your Eclipse Market Place and search for "Eclipse Color Theme",install it.
than go to windows> preferences> appearances> color theme, select your favorite style, and enjoy.
 [For more info read hare.](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme#.UD-q1qDi6So)

Comment: I don't have the market place in the menu and I can't find any place to download it!? it seem like I can't use the market place if I have the classic version installed, Juno!? Must I have Indigo instead!?

Comment: Try Help> Eclipse Marketplace. Which version of Eclipse do you have?

Comment: Hi again! I don't have any Eclipse Marketsplace inside the help menu. The version is 4.2.0

Comment: hi 3D-kreativ, i'm using eclipse, doesn't make sense you don't have Eclipse Marketplace. what do you have under the "help" menu??

Comment: 3D-kreativ, you are right the market place isn't included in the classic version, however you can download and install him from hare [link](http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/), or you can probably install the Color Theme by downloading the source code from [link](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme) and place it in the plugin folder in your eclipse home directory.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Juno (4.2) it's possible to completely customize the look and feel of Eclipse via CSS, but doing so yourself isn't exactly trivial. You can get the "old" style theme (Indigo) easily via changing a Preference, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893410/old-style-tabs-in-eclipse-juno).

Here are a couple of other related SO questions and answers:

- [Eclipse 4 Juno themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980102/eclipse-4-juno-themes)
- [eclipse Juno custom workbench colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289312/eclipse-juno-custom-workbench-colors)

Comment: Thanks, that was better, but I still don't have this Eclipse Marketsplace in my Help menu to change the themes!?